# Unable to set Android SDK Path in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to set the Android SDK Path on a fresh install of Android Studio for Ubuntu 14.04. Clicking 'Apply' and 'OK' do not do anything, even though the supplied path is valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My Android SDK directory did not have the necessary permissions.

I blindly updated them with

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /urs/bin/android-studio/
```

and it now works.

I reported a bug for this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73155

Comment: No, do not use 777 permission for this.

Answer (score 1):

This error does appear to be linked to file permissions. Another option rather than granting read write and execute rights to everyone is to change the owner/group of the files like so:

```
sudo chown -R UserNameHere:UserGroupHere android-studio
```

Comment: This is much more appropriate